# Why can't I install pyler module?

Tags: python

I get an error while I try to import the pyler module in python. I have uninstalled and then installed the module many times, and also with the .whl file, but still only the info file is generated.

`import pyler`

When I write this, I get

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Tanav\VsCode\tut1\Python proj\smth.py", line 1, in <module> import pyler ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyler'`

I use python version 3.8.5 on windows 10 64-bit machine.
Please help

Comment: are you using any virtual environment? or open source python environment?

Comment: No, but I use vscode @SubbuVidyaSekar

Comment: how did you install it

Comment: First using vscode terminal, and after uninstalling ,using powershell also